# windows phone 8 listbox grid setting inner elements opacity to full

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

the problem with this code is that i have set the opacity of the grid to 0.5 and that make my grid box transparent(that is fine), but the problem is that the text and the image and the checkbox should be seen in full opacity. how can i make my grid transparent without affecting the inner elements?

**tried:**

i have make a stackpanel in the datatemplate and was trying to place it inside the grid with the margin property but the stackpanel cannot be made inside the listbox's datatemplate with grid. any solution to that

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BookCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>                   
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel  ItemHeight="200" ItemWidth="200" Margin="10"/>                 
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="#12161e" Opacity="0.5" Tap="Grid_Tap_1"  Margin="10,-5,0,20" Height="200" Width="200">
                        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1"  Margin="145,-15,-15,0" x:Name="Chkcategories" Click="Chkcategories_Click" >
                            <Image Margin="-80,-140,-15,0" Height="20" Width="20" Source="{Binding ElementName=Chkcategories, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToImageSource} }"></Image>
                        </CheckBox>                         
                        <Image Width="50" Opacity="100" Height="50" Margin="30,30,0,0" Source="Assets/icons/food.png"></Image>
                            <TextBlock  Margin="40, 80, 0, 0" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"></TextBlock>

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Opacity setting is inherited for all child elements if set directly in the Grid Opacity=... setting. You should instead use opacity like this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#12161e" Opacity="0.5" />
</Grid.Background>
... content ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use alpha channel (0-255).

255 (max) * 0.5 (your opacity) = 127.5 => 128 => 80 hex

```
<Grid Background="#8012161e" ...
```